# The function of "as"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, as

> However, in response to the N.S.A. revelations, Google has fast-tracked its plan to encrypt data **as** it zips between its own data centers to prevent it from being subject to intelligence-agency prying.
>
> [Source](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/elements/2013/09/the-nsa-versus-encryption.html)

Is the function of "as" in the above sentence the same as in this sentence:

> The world as we know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [sense one in Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as):

> (often preceded by *just*) while; when; at the time that

The data will be encrypted when it's transferred between data centers.

Comment: But my interpretation is also possible?　I mean, "encryption data that zips between its own data centers."

Comment: @kih1930 No, it definitely means *while*. The data is encrypted *while it goes through the data centers*. That's certainly what they meant.

Comment: @kih1930 Your second example is the second sense: "in the way that". It would become "The world [in the way that] we know it."